# Xcode Ipad Simulator Background Image Stretched

Tags: xcode, image, background, simulator, stretched

Whenever I run my app through any of the Ipad simulators in xcode, the background image is stretched or zoomed in and looks really abnormal.  When I run the simulator for the Iphones the background image is fine.  Does anybody know what might be causing this?

edit:

Please see the following screenshots of the launchimage (how it should look) and the background once the app is done loading.

My launchimage and how the background should look:
[image]

How the background looks once the app is done loading.  Notice it is zoomed in: 
[image]

Comment: Can you give us more info, like screenshot of iPad/iPhone simulator, it would be easier to see the problem like that.

Comment: I just added the screenshots for your convenience.  Thanks Bojan!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed your original image has resolution of 2048x1536, which is Retina display's resolution.

*Solution:* Rename it adding a suffix of `@2x` (e.g.: if your image's called `background.png`, rename it to `background@2x.png`).